# Apply custom attributes inside attributes.phtml

Tags: custom-attributes

My site has a tabs section, one that displays the product description and the other tab lists the `getAdditionalData()` like SKU and weight of the product.
There is a custom class that outputs the preselected options in the main product area. I would like to place those preselected option values inside of the tab list but for some reason I can't call the class from within attributes.phtml

Is there another way I should be doing this?

```
$_preset = $this->getLayout()->getBlockSingleton('Block_Catalog_Product_Preset');
$_option = $_preset->getOption();
$_presetData = $_preset->getPresetData($_option->getPreset());
```

The markup in the preset.phtml that loads the preset options is essentially the same other than `$_preset->` it is `$_this->`

It gives me the error `Call to a member function getPreset() on null`
Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Comment: You need to display custom attribute in detail page tab?

Comment: Yes. Although it is not an actual magento 'attribute'.

Answer (score 0):

Although I didn't figure out how to do this through Magento php, I did manage to achieve what needed to be done through JavaScript by creating an array[], grabbing the pre-selected values from the product and then dumping the array in the correct tab.
Here is a basic example of what I did. Hope it will help anyone else facing this problem-

In JS file:

```
  var my_array = new Array();   

  $('.preset-value').each(function(){
     my_array['' + $(this).attr('id') + ''] = $(this).text();
     my_array.push($(this).text());
  });
```

Create a div `<div class="preset-block">` in the tab.phtml (could be description.phtml or attributes.phtml - Wherever your tab code resides). Output for the tab div in JS file:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < my_array.length; i++) {
    $('.preset-block').append('<span>' + my_array[i] + '</span>');
  }
```